# Building a linear regression model with cross-validation in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, cross-validation

I have about 1.3k samples of leaf temperature and I'm trying to predict this temperature using atmospheric variables such as air temperature, solar radiation, wind, and humidity.

I started off simple with a multivariate linear regression model, but I wanted to kick it up a notch in terms of accuracy so I decided to try out the leave-one-out cross-validation method in order to get the best model output. I ultimately seek to collect the coefficients and intercept so that I can use this model for later.

Now, from what I understand, cross-validation can have two purposes. The first seems to be to compare the accuracy of your model with that of other models and to decide which is best after going through numerous training data.

The second purpose (and the one I'm trying to use) is that you can use cross-validation in order to improve the accuracy of one single model. In other words, the final model that I'm trying to build has been built after considering all the possible training sets. I have a feeling like I could be all wrong for that 2nd purpose.

Anyways, inspired by what I've seen (most notably [this](https://codeburst.io/cross-validation-calculating-r%C2%B2-and-accuracy-scores-after-loocv-5bd1015a50ec) and [this](https://dziganto.github.io/cross-validation/data%20science/machine%20learning/model%20tuning/python/Model-Tuning-with-Validation-and-Cross-Validation/)), I've developed the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
#Leave ont out cross validation (LOOCV)
#Y_data and X_data are both pandas df
loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.get_n_splits(X_data)
ytests = []
ypreds = []
All_coef = list()
All_intercept = list()
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X_data):
     X_train, X_test = X_data.iloc[train_index], X_data.iloc[test_index]
     Y_train, Y_test = Y_data.iloc[train_index], Y_data.iloc[test_index]

     model = LinearRegression()
     model.fit(X=X_train, y=Y_train)
     Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

     All_coef.append(model.coef_)
     All_intercept.append(model.intercept_)

     ytests += Y_test.values.tolist()[0]
     ypreds += list(Y_pred)
rr = metrics.r2_score(ytests, ypreds)
ms_error = metrics.mean_squared_error(ytests, ypreds)
```

But this is weird because the linear regression is within the cross-validation loop-thing and not out of it, so I can't really get a final model out of this. Am I suppose to have the `LinearRegression()` and `.fit()` outside of the loop as well? If so then how do I validate the final model?

I was also thinking of how I'm supposed to get the coefficients and the intercept from my model. If I am to keep the linear regression within the loop, that means I'll acquire coefficients for every training set. Would it be wise to make some sort of mean out of it?

Thank you so much for your consideration!

Comment: You can store the coefficients and accuracy for each iteration, and finally outside of the loop print out the coefficients with the best accuracy. Then, you can create a model with those coefficients. Assuming your data does not change, you can hardcode the best coefficients into your program and delete the for loop so you're not running it every time. However, in your present code, I see no indication that you are changing the parameters of `LinearRegression` per iteration of the for loop, so you need to fix that.

Comment: @Tomothy32 By parameters, do you mean the coefficients? I changed my code in perhaps a way that could respond to what you mentionned. Thx

Comment: My bad, forget what I said about changing the parameters, I forgot it's a simple regression. Anyway, about your changed code. You are storing the coefficients and intercepts, but you probably want to store the accuracy of each model, too. This way, you know which set of coefficients did the best.

Comment: you should throw away all the coefficients and store only the performance. Train a final model on all data, and keep the cv performance as estimate of performance on unseen for that model

Comment: @Tomothy32 Kk cool I'll try that out.

Comment: @00__00__00 Sorry i'm not sure I understand that last part. If I use all the data on the final model, how am I going to be able to test it?

Comment: you dont need to test it. you use it on new data. performance evaluation on the same data that you used for testing would be overoptimistic.

Comment: @00__00__00 Fair enough, but if I don't have new data for the moment? I have to wait another few months before I can do any new validation.

Comment: the validation performance is given by the average of the performance for each model in the for loop. That validation performance (mean r2+-std) does not refer to any of the cv models (the ones in the loop) but rather to the model trained on all data